# Remove dot(.) from amout value using sqlite query

Tags: sql, sqlite, sum

I want to remove dots (.) before decimal places in my amount value. Below is my database table 
[image]

**Query**

```
SELECT sum( REPLACE( REPLACE( amt, ',', '' ) , ' ', '' ) ) FROM  amt_demo
```

when I run the above query I get the following output.

**Output**
[image]

But I want the total sum of the values like:

```
1333.00
100000.50
100000.00
123456789
123456789
123456789
---------------
370571700.50
```

Any idea how can I solve this?

Comment: Maybe it is easier to prevent such weird dots and commas to get into your database.

Comment: moffeltje : My application allow all type of amount format so user can entered whatever he wants so that why i enter dot(.) before decimal places

Comment: but you can convert the format before storing it to the database, right?

Comment: moffeltje : ya i know but at display time whatever user entered format that format i want to display in my application

Comment: moffeltje : That is issue i can not change format during storing time because if i change format in storing time than after getting value form database i can not get user entered format

Comment: Then store both the value and the weird string.

Comment: CL : you mean to say i store user entered format and one other format with replace special character during entry time ?

Answer (score 1):

Use Maths CEIL function

> SELECT CEIL(sum( REPLACE( REPLACE( amt, ',', '' ) , ' ', '' ) ))

Comment: Lalit Patel : i use your query i gave me SQlite syntax error message like `[ no such function: CEIL ]`